# parallels and meridians doesn't show up on baseman

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

parallels and meridians doesn't show up on baseman. What should I do? I guess it's been totally covered? I tried setting `zorder=1` when creating the map but it didn't work

```
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=pr.bounds[0],llcrnrlat=pr.bounds[1],urcrnrlon=pr.bounds[2],urcrnrlat=pr.bounds[3],epsg=4326)
map.arcgisimage(service='World_Street_Map',xpixels=1500,verbose=True)

map.scatter(ht.lng,ht.lat,c=ht_labels,alpha=0.5)

map.drawparallels(np.arange(pr.bounds[0],pr.bounds[2],0.2),labels=[1,0,0,0])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(pr.bounds[1],pr.bounds[3],0.2),labels=[0,0,0,1])

plt.savefig('./fig/ht_clust1.png',dpi=1000)
plt.clf()
```

Comment: What is `pr.bounds`?

Comment: loaded shapefile

Comment: I mean more what is it actually? Have a read on how to create a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically need at least some bits of your actual data.

Comment: you can assume they are arbitrary number. because they come from bounding box of the map

Answer (score 0):

You are using the longitude bounds to plot parallels and the latitude lines to plot the meridians - the wrong way round! Switch your calls around:

```
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(pr.bounds[0],pr.bounds[2],0.2),labels=[1,0,0,0])
map.drawparallels(np.arange(pr.bounds[1],pr.bounds[3],0.2),labels=[0,0,0,1])
```